# Nginx 502 bad gateway solved with server restart

Tags: nginx, server

I was getting 502 problem, And reading previous posts didn't help me.
It use to be work correctly but it had stopped responding without any server modification.
After all effort which didn't work I restarted server and everything worked fine.
I have 2 questions here:
1- How to get more information what causes nginx to fail? Is there any log?
2- What can be possible reasons restarting nginx solved the issue?

Comment: 1. Nginx's error log should've been defined in your main `nginx.conf` file. 2. The 502 error is most likely due to a `proxy_pass` type of request. It could be that a a process like `supervisor` or `gunicorn` died but the server restart started those processes automatically. You'll need to post your Nginx configuration and any info about the apps you're running